# How to relate this integration with the integral expansion of special functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, special-functions, differential-calculus, bessel-functions

I encounter the following integral when trying to find the inverse Fourier transform of the characteristic function of a certain sum of random variables. Here, $p\ge0$, $q\ge0$ are real, and $n,a,b$ are integers. I want to compute the following integral:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{p \cos (a \tau) + q \cos (b \tau)}
\cos (n \tau) \frac{d \tau}{2 \pi}$$

This is a generalization of a Bessel integral, in that for $q = 0$, $a=1$ I know that:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{p \cos (\tau)}\cos (n \tau) \frac{d \tau}{2 \pi}
=I_n(p)$$

where $I_n(p)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: there is no closed form expression for this general integral.